# Knockout viewmodel mapping stops subscription firing

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-3.0

I have following master viewmodel

```
var masterVM = (function() {
  this.PatientViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(new PatientViewModel());
  this.MedicalBenefit = new MedicalBenefitViewModel(this.PatientViewModel);
})();
```

and following view models

```
var PatientViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;

  self.FirstName = ko.observable();
  self.LastName = ko.observable();
  self.NationalHealthFundId = ko.mapping.fromJS(null);

  self.NationalHealthFundId.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    alert("subscribe from patient");
  });
};

var MedicalBenefitViewModel = function (patient) {
    var self = this;

    self.patient = patient;
};
```

and somewhere in custom binding (bind to patient):

```
...

var observable = valueAccessor();

ko.mapping.fromJS(patient, {}, observable);

...
```

where patient is simple plain json object representing patient.

After custom binding execution, the subscription ( alert("subscribe from patient"); ) stops working, why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set `self.NationalHealthFundId = ko.mapping.fromJS(null);`. You can only subscribe to an observable.  For example, this works:

```js
var PatientViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;

  self.FirstName = ko.observable();
  self.LastName = ko.observable();
  self.NationalHealthFundId = ko.observable();

  self.NationalHealthFundId.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    alert("subscribe from patient");
  });
};

var vm = new PatientViewModel()
ko.applyBindings(vm);

vm.NationalHealthFundId(1);
vm.NationalHealthFundId(2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
```